# Sorting in MySQL query based on field value ascending but mixing together at the same time

Tags: mysql

I have a database with table values as priority and name.
I want to fetch the records with lowest priority as top and then lowest as last

So I wrote like this `order by priority assc` and it works perfectly. But what I am looking for is this.

More than 1 field can have same priority so right now it comes as all the data with priority 1 together and then all with priority 2 etc. etc.

**What I need is** **One data with priority 1 first and then One with priority 2 and then priority 3 and then when there is no more data with any other priority it should be repeated again as priority 1 and 2 and 3 etc etc etc.**

I know this can be done with `sorting or group`

Until now I tried `select * from table order by priority asc`

Any advice?

**EDIT**

```
select *, COUNT(p2.`pr_priority`) AS before_me_same_priority 
from (select * from x_cou_courses,x_cou_prov,x_cou_datav where ( (cou_name like '%%' || cou_merchant_name like '%%' || '' IN (cou_key) ) and (cou_status='1' and cou_api=pr_id  and (cou_name !='') and cou_version=dtv_id and dtv_status='1' ) ) ) 
AS p1 LEFT JOIN x_cou_prov AS p2 ON p1.`pr_priority` = p2.pr_priority AND p1.`pr_priority` > p2.`pr_priority`
GROUP BY p1.`pr_priority` ORDER BY before_me_same_priority, p2.pr_priority
```

I am doing this now, but i get before_me_same_priority as 0 in all and i get only 4-5 data i have more than 5k data

**Table x_cou_prov has the priority field as pr_priority**

Comment: try to fetch data with DISTINCT

Comment: Post sample data (just a few values) and expected output.

Comment: What version of MySQL? It matters because windowing functions can be an approach to solving this problem, and they're only available in 8+.

Comment: @O.Jones This is the version of my mysql 10.1.34-MariaDB

Comment: @SandhyaSrishti Thank you for commenting but that will only select one data we want to show all the data not only 1 the data is being search for keywords like like '%$q%'

Comment: No windowing functions in MariaDB 10.1, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you have the following table:

| id | task | priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | t1 | 2 |
| 2 | t2 | 1 |
| 3 | t3 | 1 |
| 4 | t4 | 3 |
| 5 | t5 | 2 |
| 6 | t6 | 1 |
| 7 | t7 | 2 |
| 8 | t8 | 3 |
| 9 | t9 | 3 |
| 10 | t10 | 1 |
| 11 | t11 | 2 |

The query:

```
SELECT p1.*, COUNT(p2.id) AS before_me_same_priority 
FROM priorities AS p1
LEFT JOIN priorities AS p2 ON p1.priority = p2.priority AND p1.id > p2.id
GROUP BY p1.id
ORDER BY before_me_same_priority, priority
;
```

will output the result:

| id | task | priority | before_me_same_priority |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | t2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | t1 | 2 | 0 |
| 4 | t4 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | t3 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | t5 | 2 | 1 |
| 8 | t8 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | t6 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | t7 | 2 | 2 |
| 9 | t9 | 3 | 2 |
| 10 | t10 | 1 | 3 |
| 11 | t11 | 2 | 3 |

Comment: This Works perfect, but its TOO slow for the number of data i have, i have about 30k data there and this is taking ages to start

Comment: Try to add an index on priority column